# Is Amazon SimpleDB a good choice for my data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I'm working on a database that stores user-created surveys.  The database needs to store a unique ID for each survey.  Using SQL, I'd just use a SERIAL column type so each row has an auto-incrementing numeric key.

SimpleDB seems to store everything as a string, meaning I would have to generate a unique key myself.  Since this key will be part of the URL, I think a UUID is just too long.  I want to be able to load a survey with something like:

foo.com/1a

Is there any way to have SimpleDB generate a unique row ID for each item you store?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so you're asking for opinions here.... I would choice any other storage mechanism over simpledb. For example, you could easily go with MongoDB as a document storage alternative to a relational DB and get more benefits than with SimpleDB.

As far as wanting a short unique URL, you can search and find a ruby implementation to turn an ID into a shorted ID. http://blog.kischuk.com/2008/06/23/create-tinyurl-like-urls-in-ruby/

That implementation will turn 1174229 into "7sH_" (according to the post. YMMV)

So, you'd have something like

```
class Survey
  include Mongoid::Document

  def to_param
    generate_url(self.id)
  end
end
```

in routes

```
resources :surverys, :path=>''
```

And that would create

**http://yourapp/7sh_**

Of course this technique can work for non-mongo installs.

Comment: Thanks!  We've actually decided to go with MongoDB and MongoHQ to host..  The more we looked into SimpleDB, the more we didn't like it.  Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

[SDB Explorer](http://www.sdbexplorer.com/) supports bulk upload from MYSQL to Amazon SimpleDB. You can upload your MYSQL data to Amazon SimpleDB using [Upload](http://www.sdbexplorer.com/documentation/simpledb--how-to-upload-mysql-data-on-amazon-simpledb.html) feature. While upload SDB Explorer generates unique ID. Even you can choose you own MYSQL filed as a itemName() i.e. unique id for Amazon SimpleDB.